# Take string from one method and use it in another (Same class)

Tags: java, android, methods, get, set

I saw a lot of different posts with same issue, but I could not figure out with my situation.

First part

```
 AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    String result = OpenALPR.Factory.create(MainActivity.this, ANDROID_DATA_DIR).recognizeWithCountryRegionNConfig("eu", "", destination.getAbsolutePath(), openAlprConfFile, 10);

                    Log.d("-", result);

                    try {
                        final Results results = new Gson().fromJson(result, Results.class);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if (results == null || results.getResults() == null || results.getResults().size() == 0) {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "It was not possible to detect the licence plate.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    resultTextView.setText("It was not possible to detect the licence plate.");
                                } else {
                                    resultTextView.setText("Plate: " + results.getResults().get(0).getPlate()
                                            // Trim confidence to two decimal places
                                            + " Confidence: " + String.format("%.2f", results.getResults().get(0).getConfidence()) + "%"
                                            // Convert processing time to seconds and trim to two decimal places
                                            + " Processing time: " + String.format("%.2f", ((results.getProcessing_time_ms() / 1000.0) % 60)) + " seconds");


                                    String str = results.getResults().get(0).getPlate();
                                    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
                                    editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.AllCaps()});
                                    editText.setText(str, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

                                    plateNumberEdited = editText.toString();


                                }
                            }


                        });
```

And I would like to use "**plateNumberEdited**" here to send value to another activity and based on this value display the results

```
Button GoToNewActivity = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
        GoToNewActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DVLAresult.class);
                intent.putExtra("dvlaNumber", plateNumberEdited);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Which is located in onCreate method

This is full code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    Button GoToNewActivity = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
    GoToNewActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DVLAresult.class);
            intent.putExtra("dvlaNumber", plateNumberEdited);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    ANDROID_DATA_DIR = this.getApplicationInfo().dataDir;

    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            checkPermission();
        }
    });
    resultTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    resultTextView.setText("Welcome to CarAnalyser ");
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        final ProgressDialog progress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading", "Parsing result...", true);
        final String openAlprConfFile = ANDROID_DATA_DIR + File.separatorChar + "runtime_data" + File.separatorChar + "openalpr.conf";
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 10;

        // Picasso requires permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(destination).fit().centerCrop().into(imageView);
        resultTextView.setText("Processing");

        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String result = OpenALPR.Factory.create(MainActivity.this, ANDROID_DATA_DIR).recognizeWithCountryRegionNConfig("eu", "", destination.getAbsolutePath(), openAlprConfFile, 10);

                Log.d("OPEN ALPR", result);

                try {
                    final Results results = new Gson().fromJson(result, Results.class);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (results == null || results.getResults() == null || results.getResults().size() == 0) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "It was not possible to detect the licence plate.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                resultTextView.setText("It was not possible to detect the licence plate.");
                            } else {
                                resultTextView.setText("Plate: " + results.getResults().get(0).getPlate()
                                        // Trim confidence to two decimal places
                                        + " Confidence: " + String.format("%.2f", results.getResults().get(0).getConfidence()) + "%"
                                        // Convert processing time to seconds and trim to two decimal places
                                        + " Processing time: " + String.format("%.2f", ((results.getProcessing_time_ms() / 1000.0) % 60)) + " seconds");


                                String str = results.getResults().get(0).getPlate();
                                EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
                                editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.AllCaps()});
                                editText.setText(str, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

                                plateNumberEdited = editText.toString();


                            }
                        }


                    });

                } catch (JsonSyntaxException exception) {
                    final ResultsError resultsError = new Gson().fromJson(result, ResultsError.class);

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            resultTextView.setText(resultsError.getMsg());
                        }
                    });
                }

                progress.dismiss();
            }


        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not having just two methods. Its two different threads.

Comment: where do you declare plateNumberEdited?

Comment: @Stultuske I would guess he's having like a class member called plateNumberEdited

Comment: Declare outside as public String plateNumberEdited;

Comment: @AndreasBrunnet meaning he can use it there, but whether or not everything is synchronized an all ..

Comment: @Stultuske That was my concern too. He's sharing data between threads and he is not synchronizing the data.

Comment: It's not two different threads. Notice `runOnUiThread`. Both accesses to `plateNumberEdited` will be on the main Activity thread, so no need to synchronize. @J.FOG To help understand the question, can you pinpoint the problem you are experiencing in your approach?

Comment: @szym Problem is that I would like to use text from editable field, and send  this String to another activity by pressing button send

Comment: @J.FOG Off the top of my head, you'd likely need to make sure that the `GoToNewActivity` button is only clickable after `plateNumberEdited` is set by the inner `Runnable`. You could consider setting the button state to disabled and only re-enabling it once the value is set.

Comment: @J.FOG I understand what you'd like to do, but what seems to be the problem in your existing code? What happens instead? Do you see the result in your `resultTextView`? What happens when the `GoToNewActivity` button is pressed?

Comment: @szym ou you about this, so not errors on the code, when I type in in this editable fiend anything and press SEND button, it's redirect me to DVLAresult activity and it's just empty no text at all. Basically result is not showing up.

Comment: @szym if I will change intent.putExtra("dvlaNumber", plateNumberEdited);  to intent.putExtra("dvlaNumber", "TESTEST"); and press button send , it will actually display on second activity TESTEST, so sending value is working but how to get value from editText and send it, this is the question.